# Point an external DNS to Docker DNS

Tags: dns, docker

I'm just getting started with Docker and if I can make this work I will switch all my services to it.

I originally disliked Docker because I thought the only way to access containers was to forward ports to the docker host. Later I discovered Docker networking and the `ipvlan` network. The ability to route a sub network to my existing network infrastructure was ideal and all devices could access containers with a simple static route.

There was one problem remaining. DNS. Currently I have a Windows server that hosts AD, internal DNS and DHCP servers. The DHCP server dynamically updates DNS records. That worked fine with my current virtual machine setup, but the Docker hosts automatically assigns IP addresses to containers. Containers can resolve each other by their container name.

Because I'm lazy and don't want to add DNS entries manually I would like to add a DNS server container, that resolves the Docker hosts. For easier interpretation I have drawn a picture of my setup:

A hand-drawn diagram of my setup:

[image: A hand-drawn diagram of my setup]

Let's say `a.home` is the internal domain name for my infrastructure. All devices on the network have a main DNS server on the address `10.0.0.2`. `docker.a.home` points to the docker host.

Inside the docker host there is a `10.0.1.0/24` network, that has all the docker container's connected to it. Containers resolve each other as intended. I would like to configure a DNS server container on the docker host, that would resolve `container-name.docker.a.home` domains to the correct IP addresses.

Example:

1. `c1.docker.a.home` would resolve to `10.0.1.2`
2. `c2.docker.a.home` would resolve to `10.0.1.3`

The main DNS server would have a `NS` record that points to the Docker DNS server container.

I may have overcomplicated my setup, if you have an alternative more efficient way to achieve the same result I'm open to suggestions. If my setup makes sense to you, I would very much appreciate some help or an example docker compose file to help me get started.

Thank you very much in advance.